# Including file from various folders

Tags: php

This has been giving me a headache. I've read multiple questions but none helped me.

So I need to include php files from different folders. Here's how my structure looks like. I'm using WAMP.

```
/C
    /wamp
      /www
       /project1
        /main
         /backend
          -class.common.php
          -inc.config.php
            /providers
             /google
              -google.functions.php
```

So as clear from the structure above, class.common.php is under folder backend (Which is under folder main).

Now, I'm trying to include **class.common.php** in **google.functions.php** using THIS code :-

```
include '../../class.common.php';
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. I've even tried working with the `__DIR__` constant. No luck. What's the most robust way to achieve my result?

PHP Error Log.

```
    [15-Jun-2016 22:16:25 Europe/Paris] PHP Warning:  include(../../_inc_config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\yele\main\backend\api_providers\rech\api_functions.php on line 3

[15-Jun-2016 22:16:25 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[15-Jun-2016 22:16:25 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\yele\main\backend\ajax.php:0

[15-Jun-2016 22:16:25 Europe/Paris] PHP   2. include() C:\wamp\www\yele\main\backend\ajax.php:2

[15-Jun-2016 22:16:25 Europe/Paris] PHP   3. include() C:\wamp\www\yele\main\backend\class.apibase.php:3

[15-Jun-2016 22:16:25 Europe/Paris] PHP   4. include() C:\wamp\www\yele\main\backend\api_providers\rech\base_lib.php:2

[15-Jun-2016 22:16:25 Europe/Paris] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '../../_inc_config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\yele\main\backend\api_providers\rech\api_functions.php on line 3

[15-Jun-2016 22:16:25 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[15-Jun-2016 22:16:25 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\yele\main\backend\ajax.php:0

[15-Jun-2016 22:16:25 Europe/Paris] PHP   2. include() C:\wamp\www\yele\main\backend\ajax.php:2

[15-Jun-2016 22:16:25 Europe/Paris] PHP   3. include() C:\wamp\www\yele\main\backend\class.apibase.php:3

[15-Jun-2016 22:16:25 Europe/Paris] PHP   4. include() C:\wamp\www\yele\main\backend\api_providers\rech\base_lib.php:2

[15-Jun-2016 22:16:25 Europe/Paris] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class common in C:\wamp\www\yele\main\backend\class.common.php on line 5

[15-Jun-2016 22:16:25 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[15-Jun-2016 22:16:25 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\yele\main\backend\ajax.php:0

[15-Jun-2016 22:16:25 Europe/Paris] PHP   2. include() C:\wamp\www\yele\main\backend\ajax.php:3
```

Comment: change your `include`s to `include_once`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm reading your diagram properly, but given the following:

if the full path to `google.functions.php` is

```
C:/wamp/www/project1/main/backend/providers/google/google.functions.php
```

and the full path to `class.common.php` is

```
C:/wamp/www/project1/main/backend/class.common.php
```

to include that file relative wherever it is, then `__DIR__` should work

```
<?php
include_once __DIR__.'/../../class.common.php';
```

---

## Update

From the looks of your error logs, you have a couple problems.

- the include failure is happening in `C:\wamp\www\yele\main\backend\api_providers\rech\api_functions.php` which is calling a path relative include `include(../../_inc_config.php)`, which changes depending on which file the script is included from. so this is odd for a vendor, but you can try changing the line to `include(__DIR__.'/../../_inc_config.php')` to force it to include relative to the actual including file, which is coincidentally my original answer for your problem.
- you have a fatal error with redeclaring the `common` class, so use `include_once` or `require_once`

Comment: Did not work. Another thing I've noticed is, if I include the file in a test file (has no code other than including the file), then it works fine.  But when I include it in a file which had some good code, then it doesn't work.

Comment: so you're saying the include works, but it's conflicting with other code? then that's a different problem. make sure you're using [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: I am using error reporting. I've updated my question with the recent logs.

Comment: I think this solve it. However, a new error `Cannot redeclare class` came up. I think I'll take some time to fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

firsty, getting real/physical path can be more usable

```
include realpath('/../../class.common.php');
```